# Some clients get 'Certificate-based authentication failed' error on a cert, w/ all browsers

Tags: browser, certificate

I'm hosting multiple SSL sites on multiple Ubuntu / LAMP servers. The servers have quite standard setup, eg. no client certificate configuration is in place. The vast majority of users are fine, but there have now been two cases where a particular cert gives an error on two client machines (Vista and Windows 7). I've debugged the case with the Vista user, and this is what I have so far:

- the problem only occurs with a particular `*.domain.tld` cert. Other very similar certs served from the same server with the exact same settings work fine. Other certs from other servers (banks, Gmail, etc) work fine, too.
- http traffic to the same server IP works fine.
- the problem happens at least on Firefox 35, Chrome 40 and IE (unspecified).
- Chrome gives the error **Certificate-based authentication failed**.
- Firefox gives the error **ssl_error_access_denied_alert**.
- IE, naturally, gives some obscure "web page cannot be displayed" mumbling.
- the machine is running Windows Defender, Windows firewall and a version of F-Secure. Tried with disabling all of those, didn't help.
- Family Safety is not enabled.
- this doesn't seem to be a CA chain error.
- this doesn't seem to be an error related to invalid server certificates.
- the clock is correctly set on both machines

It seems to me there's something wrong on the client's machine. What could that be? Misconfiguration, malware, something else?

Network dump shows that the SSL handshake doesn't get very far: (that's all the packets I saw on the server)

[image: network dump]
(The site is served on the standard port `443`. The server port `6443` shown here is mapped to the standard `443` on a firewall.)

One more thing: in the server log I saw some HTTP (not HTTPS) requests coming from the client's IP with `User-Agent: Microsoft Windows Network Diagnostics`, and also one request with no `Host` or `User-Agent` header. This happened during the over-the-phone debugging with the user. The user hasn't certainly made this request by hand.

Still one more thing: the client can successfully access the same sites with HTTP.

Comment: I am going to guess this is a case where only certain versions of SSL are enabled on the client's machine.  You don't indicate what version of Windows they are using.  The SSL error itself indicates the authentication is failing which seems to indicate the client is trying to communicate with a version of SSl your server is rejecting.

Comment: have this person disable [`Family Safety`](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-security/my-family-member-can-not-gain-access-to-any/390c3234-7a5e-40c1-9e5f-0c49fad6c919?page=2) if its enabled.

Comment: Ramhound: the Windows versions are Vista and 7. Another cert with the exact same settings works, so IMHO it shouldn't be an SSL version issue. The server support TLS 1.0-1.2 (no SSLv2 or SSLv3).

Comment: TLS 1.0-1.2 is still SSL, they decided to name what is initially the next version after SSLv3 something else entirely.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry for ambiguous phrasing. I meant to say that another IP on the same server hosts another cert and with the exact same SSL/TLS settings (that is, TLS 1.x only), and that config works fine on the client.

Comment: I still suspect a client SSL configuration problem.  Do other machines within this same client network work?

Comment: The client is a home user, using a mobile broadband connection from a major ISP. No other users in the network, I suppose. I wonder whether there exists a valid scenario where the client can connect to one host but not another with an identical conf in the next IP. I'd expect to find that the user has managed to eg. blacklist the cert or in *some* application. I just don't know where to start looking.

Comment: You have verified he isn't using the Family Safety feature within windows?  Additionally confirm the certificate has been added to the Windows certificate store.